# suggestion needed about cocos2d c++ source code sturcture please

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, project-structure

I am a Java developer. Recently I am researching writing game with c++ and cocos2dx engine. When I trying to read other people's source codes, I find almost all people put all .cpp and .h files into one directory, which make a Java developer a bit of confused: how to maintenance the source code in the future?

So can I get some suggestions on how to organise my c++ files with cocos2dx?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: No reasonable C++ compiler is going to have any problem dealing with header files in a separate directory. Put your files where you think is sensible, and don't worry about it.

Comment: in java, we usually use package to divide modules, so is it recommended to use the namespace and directory do the same in c++?